# Running express-stormpath locally (register doesn't work?)

Tags: node.js, stormpath, express-stormpath

I'm trying to run [`express-stormpath`](https://github.com/stormpath/express-stormpath) on my local NodeJS project, but I cannot do anything to sign up to get my API key. When I simply do:

```
var stormpath = require("express-stormpath");

app.use(stormpath.init(app, {
    web: {
        register: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }
}));
```

I was told by all the documentation, that I should be able to visit http://localhost:3000/login and http://localhost:3000/register to verify the "installation" works, but I'm just getting timed out. My console reads:

> Error: API key ID and secret is required.

When I go to the website, I can ONLY log in and when I go to https://api.stormpath.com/register to register an account, it just redirects me to the login page (got the link from [here](https://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/express/latest/setup.html)).

What do I do to register an account? This is one of the most frustrating things I have ever dealt with.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the frustration.

Stormpath isn't accepting new tenant registrations, because the [service is shutting down](https://stormpath.com/blog/stormpaths-new-path) after the team joined Okta. The functionality of Stormpath will make its way into the [Okta developer API](http://developer.okta.com/).

Source: previously at Stormpath, now at Okta.

Comment: Damn that sucks. So I'm basically stuck now and I can't develop my application, is that what you're basically saying? I find it weird why a company would shut down a service before migrating to another company. Why not keep it up and running until the very last day, and give people some good guidance to move their code to work on the new platform? Doesn't make any sense and it seems unprofessional to me.

Comment: @MortenMoulder I understand your frustration; sorry that I don't have a better answer. The service will stay running until the sunset date for any existing tenants, and we're working on migration documentation. If you have migration questions, feel free to reach out to developers@okta.com.

Comment: That's unfortunate and annoying. Sorry, but I'm going to go another route and find an alternative, because this is too unprofessional to me.